# C# Calling WinForm Class from a different class to update text displayed on WinForm element

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

So I currently have a working C# console application that I am working on converting to a WinForm app. I am trying to write a function so I can essentially replace all my Console.WriteLine() from when it was a console app, to instead display the same text to the WinForm. I wanted to write a public function that I can call from other classes, that takes a string as an argument and will display the string on the WinForm.

Essentially my main class `Program1` will run, then any time it needs to display a message it calls a method from my WinForm class `Form1` to print that message to the WinForm

I am a little confused how to do this, I created a label in the WinForm design tab and have a function that was created by visual studio

```
    private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

However wouldn't this function only be called from the winform itself? How could I create the function I described above, or is this not possible using WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

That is a method signature for an event. It doesn't necessarily be TextChanged event but likely it is (it is the naming given by VS for TextChanged on control label1. If that label1 is really a Label, then TextChanged event would be useless anyway.

For displaying things on a form, probably the best control would be a textbox control with Multiline property set to true and ReadOnly to true. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    ShowInfo("Any information string.");
}

void ShowInfo(string information)
{
    var f = new Form();
    var t = new TextBox
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        Multiline = true,
        ReadOnly = true,
        Text = information
    };
    f.Controls.Add(t);
    f.Show();
}
```

EDIT: For those who don't understand the basics, here is a more detailed version:

```
void Main()
{
    CreateInfoForm();
    ShowInfo("Any information string.");
    MessageBox.Show("Press any key to continue...");
    ShowInfo("Some other info");
}

public static void ShowInfo(string information)
{
    t.Text = information;
}

public Form f;
public static TextBox t;

void CreateInfoForm()
{
    f = new Form();
    t = new TextBox
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        Multiline = true,
        ReadOnly = true
    };
    f.Controls.Add(t);
    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: So, every time someone wants to write a new message, you are going to instantiate a new `Textbox`, set its styling properties and add it to the form.  Really?

Comment: @Flydog57, no it is not the case. It is only your perception. See public and return in help.

Comment: OK, what am I missing.  You have a `ShowInfo(string information)` method.  I'm assuming that it will be called more than once at times in your code (I'm not sure what your `Main` is doing - remember this is for a WinForms app, the `Main` function generally just calls `Application.Run`).  Each call will create a new Form, a new TextBox (added to the Controls collection) and show that form.  Seems like a very odd solution.  What do _"public and return in help"_ have to do with any of this

Comment: @Flydog57, what you are missing is I provided the simple layout. One would only create a public form, with a public textbox in it. Then a simple stastic ShowInfo(string message) would simply set theh text of the textbox. It is really flexible, you can use as is and show and dispose, or do as I outlined. No need to do something like that per form.

Comment: @Flydog57, I added another sample to make it clearer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Drop a label on your form.  Name it `UserFeedbackLabel`.  Set its Text property so that it's empty.

Then create a simple function like:

```
private void WriteUserFeedback (string message)
{
    UserFeedbackLabel.Text = message;
}
```

You may also want something like:

```
private void ClearUserFeedback()
{
    WriteUserFeedback(string.Empty);
}
```

**Variations on the theme**

If you are going to want to access this from multiple threads, then you will need to use the normal `InvokeRequired` / `Invoke` dance (which you can look up).

You could also have a second parameter that indicates whether message is simply a message or an error message and change the label's `ForeColor` property.

Finally, if you are really keen, you could put a multiline text box on the form, and append `Environment.NewLine` and the message to the textbox's `Text` property to show all messages.  *(if you do that, add vertical scrollbars to the textbox, and move the selection to the end of the text box after each append)*

**Showing Errors**

Add an `enum` like this to your project:

```
public enum MessageType
{
    Normal,
    Error,
}
```

Then change `WriteUserFeedback` to look like this:

```
private void WriteUserFeedback(string message, MessageType messageType = MessageType.Normal)
{
    UserFeedbackLabel.ForeColor = messageType == MessageType.Normal ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
    UserFeedbackLabel.Text = message;
}
```

**Supporting Multiple Threads** *(and colors)*

Here's how to use `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` to allow this method to be called from any thread, not just the UI thread.  Change `WriteUserFeedback` to look like:

```
private void WriteUserFeedback(string message, MessageType messageType = MessageType.Normal)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => WriteUserFeedback(message, messageType)));
        return;
    }
    UserFeedbackLabel.ForeColor = messageType == MessageType.Normal ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
    UserFeedbackLabel.Text = message;
}
```

The `InvokeRequired` property returns true if the code is not running on the UI thread (everything that touches your form has to run on that thread).  The `Invoke` call calls the method recursively, after marshalling the call context to the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response, I did not know about using invoke to support the multithread until now. In my main thread, how would I call this function? I tried creating an instance of the UI class but I was getting an error. Right now I have `Application.Run(new Form1());`  but this was provided by Visual Studio.

Comment: By "main thread" I mean a class I have called `Program.cs` where is want I want to be able to call that UI function

Comment: Windows Forms apps are single threaded (unless you make them multi-threaded).  Once you add a additions thread(s), life gets more complicated (since only the "UI thread" can touch the form.  With `async` and `await`, there's much less reason to have more than one thread.  But, if you do, the `InvokeRequired` / `Invoke` pattern that I showed can be very handy.  You shouldn't need to worry about extra threads

Comment: Follow any WinForms tutorial & it will say: Create a new Windows Forms project. Drop controls on the form's designer surface, and then write code for the event handlers and other functionality you want.  The `Application.Run(new Form1())` gets _your_ form class up and running and makes sure that it's capable of generating and handling events. Everything will automatically happen on the "UI thread". But, in your handlers, if you want to write messages to your users in a label, then my code will do it (just call `WriteUserFeedback ("Nope, You did something wrong");` from any of your running code

Comment: But if I want to call it from my main class after I run `Application.Run(new Form1())` since the `WriteUserFeedback()` function is part of the UI class, how can I call the function?

Comment: I also noticed while using the debugger, after 'Application.Run(new Form1())' it just stays in that thread and none of the code in my main class is run after that

Comment: The `Application.Run` call tells Windows "start this window running, let its event fire when the need to. Your `Form1` class (or whatever else you named your main form) **is** your UI class. If you drop a button on the form and double-click it, a Button Click handler will be created. If you put a call to `WriteUserFeedback()` (which should be a member of the Form1 class) in that handler, you'll see your message show up in the label

Comment: Wait sorry, my Form1 class is UI class, I agree. But my main class is a different class called Program. From Program, which is not a UI class, how would I call that 'WriteUserFeedBack()' function. Essentially I have a working program in my Program class that uses 'System.WriteLine()' currently, I would like to replace these with calling the 'WriteUserFeedBack()' function to write to the WinForm.

Comment: Thus is going on too long. Until your code executes `Application.Run`, you don't have a window (so you can't display anything on the window). After `Application.Run` runs, nothing is going to run in your Main program till the main window closes (and you app starts to shut down

Answer (score 0):

This answer provides:

> [...] a public function that I can call from other classes, that takes a string as an argument and will display the string on the WinForm.

The name of this new function is `Console.WriteLine(text)` and it will display on your Winform.

Yes, the new function is named the same as the old one. This way, if you are reusing code from your original Console app for your Winforms app, it can be copy-pasted as is without changing anything. Then, following the example below, the result will be that your string will be displayed on the Winform. But how do we keep the compiler from being confused when there are two versions of `Console.WriteLine` available? We simply add a `using` declaration at the top of every file that uses `Console.WriteLine`. The compiler uses this to disambiguate `Console` and now chooses *our* version of `Console.WriteLine` that makes the text go to the Winform.

```
using System;
using System.IV;
using Console = System.IV.Console; // Set one time for this one file.
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Now, instead of having to **essentially replace all my Console.WriteLine() from when it was a Console app** statements, you can simply copy-paste them and use them just the way they are. This outcome is made possible by writing our own `Console` class in the `System.IV` namespace. This `Console` class has a `WriteLine` method that  fires a static event named `ConsoleWrite` whenever it's called by any of your classes. It is by subscribing to this static event that you can achieve the outcome you describe, where the string will be displayed on the Winform. In this example it goes to a multiline `TextBox` named `textBoxEcho` that fully supports text that contains newlines.

*Simple example: Entering text in the Send box **calls the new version of `Console.WriteLine` in the Winforms app.*** So this is how you could create the function you described above. This screenshot demonstrates that it behaves the way you said you wanted it to.

[image: explanation]

---

This is a new class named `System.IV.Console`. Make sure the `using` statement shown above goes at the top of every class that wants to use this public function so that it will output to your Winform.

```
namespace System.IV
{
    static class Console
    {
        public static event ConsoleWriteEventHandler ConsoleWrite;
        public static void Write(object o) =>
            Console.ConsoleWrite?.Invoke(new ConsoleWriteEventArgs(o.ToString(), newLine: false));

        public static void WriteLine(object o) =>
            Console.ConsoleWrite?.Invoke(new ConsoleWriteEventArgs(o.ToString(), newLine: true));
    }

    public delegate void ConsoleWriteEventHandler(ConsoleWriteEventArgs e);
    public class ConsoleWriteEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Text { get; }
        public bool NewLine { get; }
        public ConsoleWriteEventArgs(string text, bool newLine)
        {
            Text = text;
            NewLine = newLine;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Winform code that uses the custom `Console.WriteLine` method.

```
using System;
using System.IV;
using Console = System.IV.Console; // Tells compiler to use our version file.
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace winforms_with_console_writeline
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBoxSend.KeyDown += onKeyDown;
            // Subscribe here to the static event so we can
            // do the echo when 'Console.WriteLine' is invoked.
            Console.ConsoleWrite += onConsoleWrite;
        }
        private void onKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Return)
            {
                e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

                // ================================
                // Here is the actual call in Winforms. Usage is no different.
                Console.WriteLine(textBoxSend.Text);
                // ================================

                BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBoxSend.Clear();  });
            }
        }
        // Here is where you can write the text wherever you want to put it.
        // I used 'textBoxEcho' but you might want to use 'label' instead.
        private void onConsoleWrite(ConsoleWriteEventArgs e)
        {
            var text = e.NewLine ? $"{e.Text}{Environment.NewLine}" : e.Text;
            if(InvokeRequired) Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBoxEcho.AppendText(text); });
            else textBoxEcho.AppendText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone or browse](https://github.com/IVSoftware/winforms-with-console-writeline.git) this sample from here: [Public function that can be called from any class, that takes a string as an argument and will display the string on the WinForm](https://github.com/IVSoftware/winforms-with-console-writeline.git).